# kotlin-swift interop. Как правильно сопоставить дженерики?

Tags: swift, kotlin

Делаю проект на KMM

Хочу максимизировать переиспользование кода платформами. Для этого `ViewModel` уехала в модуль `shared` и разжилась дженериком

```kotlin
/**
 * class defined as abstract (not as interface) because of Swift interop limitations
 * https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#generics
 *
 * Generics can only be defined on classes, not on interfaces (protocols in Objective-C and Swift)
 * or functions.
 */
open class ViewModel<T : Any>(initialState: T) {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(initialState)

    val currentState: T
        get() = stateFlow.value

    val stateFlow: StateFlow<T> = _state

    fun updateState(
        context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
        mapping: (currentState: T) -> T
    ) {
        GlobalScope.launch(context) { _state.emit(mapping(_state.value)) }
    }
}
```

Нужен механизм, который бы накатывал стейт не только в android, но и в ios. В android никаких проблемб работает из коробки с jetpack compose. На ios рукописный и cостоит из двух частей

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> ViewModel<T>.onChange(provideNewState: ((T) -> Unit)) : Closeable {

    val job = Job()

    stateFlow.onEach { provideNewState(it) }
        .launchIn(CoroutineScope(mainDispatcher + job))

    return object : Closeable {
        override fun close() {
            job.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

и

```swift
import Foundation
import shared

class ObservableViewModel<T : AnyObject>: ObservableObject {

    @Published var state : T
    
    init(viewModel: ViewModel<T>) {
        self.state = viewModel.currentState
        viewModel.onChange { newState in
            self.state = newState as! T
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь нужно сделать отступление и пояснить: есть [дока](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#generics) по интеропу, где сказано, что в котлин можно использовать как `<T>`, так и `<T : Any>`. Первый способ будет трактоваться в иос коде, как optional, второй, как non-optional.

`<T : AnyObject>` появилось в определении `ObservableViewModel` потому что если не расширять дженерик типом появляется ошибка

> 'ViewModel' requires that 'T' be a class type

Перехожу к проблеме:

Теперь, когда я пытаюсь инициализировать новый инстанс `ObservableViewModel` конкретным типом вью модели, которая объявлена в котлин коде

```kotlin
class DogImageViewModel(initialState: DogImageViewState)
    : ViewModel<DogImageViewState>(initialState)
```

```swift
@StateObject var vm = ObservableViewModel<DogImageViewState>(viewModel: DogImageViewModel(initialState: DogImageViewState.Loading()))
```

я получаю ошибку

> Cannot convert value of type 'DogImageViewModel' to expected argument type `ViewModel<DogImageViewState>`

То есть `DogImageViewState` не является ребёнком `AnyObject`, если я правильно понимаю природу ошибки.

Каким образом мне можно докрутить мою схему таким образом, чтобы `ObservableViewModel` могла принять любой объект унаследованный от `ViewModel`?

Comment: <T : ViewModel?>

Comment: Any и AnyObject это не про наследование. Что есть Ваш DogImageViewState?

Comment: @VAndrJ DogImageViewState это sealed class, который описывает стейт (MVI). Я уже придумал финт, чтобы не ограничивать дженерик через AnyObject: Сделал интерфейс State в shared коде, унаследовал от него DogImageViewState, и во всех функциях (и в ObservableViewModel) ограничил дженерики им. Однако всё равно получаю ошибку, что DogImageViewState не inherits State. Хотя ещё как inherits